# A question about debug on devc++ when I use c++

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, dev-c++

I don't know how to debug a vector on devc++, I used following methods to try to figure out the values in arr, but it failled.

That's my codes

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
  int main(){
        vector<int> arr(3);
        arr[0] = 0,arr[1]=1,arr[2]=3;
        printf("aaaa");
      return 0;
  }
```

I made a breakpoint on printf(). The following snippets are my errors.

[image]

It can work on VS2019. Because of my college, I have to use the devc++.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think in this case the screenshot is helpful. Not sure how you'd explain the debugger issue with only text. It makes me sad that folks are forced to use such an outdated IDE.

Comment: sry about the pics, I set a breakpoint on the line of`printf()`, I use `arr[i]` and `*(&arr[0])@3` to see the values of vector. The ide said it cannot access the memory of the address. I really don't know how to describe the issue and what wrong it is.

Answer (score 0):

to debug the vector you just need to add a watch with just the name, and if i remember correctly it should show the size and all the elements inside the vector.

Comment: I tried , it said No data fields but I pass the values to the vector. I guess there must be some problems in my devc++.